# Postgresql full-text search with other conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I have table with tsvector column, also I create index for that column. Also I have some columns(and indexes for those columns) which required for search.

For example:
Table: Vacancies
Columns: title, description(title + description = tsvector), salary(int value with index).

I want find all vacancies with text which contains in title+description and also by salary > 1000.

What column will be the first condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM vacancies 
WHERE title_description_tsvector @@ plainto_tsquery('php developer') 
  AND salary > 1000;
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM vacancies 
WHERE salary > 1000 
  AND title_description_tsvector @@ plainto_tsquery('php developer');
```

Comment: The order of the conditions combined with `AND` is irrelevant. Both queries will return the same thing.

Comment: But for using indexes it's have metter.

Comment: No, not even for the index usage it will matter. Check the execution plan using `explain analyze select ....` and you will see

Answer (score 1):

Changing the order in `WHERE` **won't affect** optimizer on its decision.

If for some reason you want to force it take one index carnality over the other (eg, you checked plans and see it uses `salary` index and then `Filter: (title_description_tsvector @@ plainto_tsquery('php developer'))` so you don't see your index on `title_description_tsvector` and you feel the optimizer is wrong). So you want to make it first chose wanted index (like with hints in Oracle), you can use CTE to try it, like:

```
EXPLAIN 
WITH pre as (SELECT * 
FROM vacancies 
WHERE title_description_tsvector @@ plainto_tsquery('php developer') 
)
SELECT * 
FROM pre 
WHERE salary > 1000;
```

I'm quite sure the cost will be higher though. If not - time to check `autovacuum`